# Mongodb : add new subdocument for each document while aggregating on a collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
db.test.aggregate([
{$match: { "colx" : 8323, "id" : {$in: [802, ....]}}},
{$group: {_id : { coly : "$coly" , id : "$id" } ,  total: {$sum: "$val"} } },
{$group: {_id: '$_id.coly', items: {$push: {id: '$_id.id', total: '$total'}} } }
])
```

the result is :

```
{
"_id": 898,
"items": [
   {
      "id" : 801
      "total" : 3355560
   },
   {
   "id" : 805
   "total" : 2760139
   }
 ]
}
```

is there a way to update all documents with an extra item after the last operation $group so that we get a result similar to this :

```
{
"_id": 898,
"items": [
   {
      "id" : 801
      "total" : 3355560
   },
   {
   "id" : 805
   "total" : 2760139
   },
   { //extra item
   "id" : 817
   "total" : 0
   }
 ]
}
```

Comment: what's the reason behind that ? and  where it comes from?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/ to update results of the aggregation

Comment: the new item is a result of a division of the totals of two other items

Comment: ***the new item is a result of a division of the totals of two other items*** How?